# I'm trying to use Cheerio extract a div element from an html using Phantom in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm trying to extract just the elements inside the class names `pod pod--rounded`.
The elements I want are in the section 'My Listings' on [this site](https://www.bhgre.com/Better-Homes-and-Gardens-Real-Estate-Big-Hill-5569c/Suzan-Jackson-300497a)

The Phantom NPM package can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom).

```
var phantom = require("phantom");
const cheerio = require('cheerio')

var _ph, _page, _outObj;

phantom.create().then(function(ph){
    _ph = ph;
    return _ph.createPage();
}).then(function(page){
    _page = page;
    return _page.open('https://www.bhgre.com/Better-Homes-and-Gardens-Real-Estate-Big-Hill-5569c/Suzan-Jackson-300497a');
}).then(function(status){
    console.log(status);
    return _page.property('content')
}).then(function(content){
  const $ = cheerio.load(content)
    console.log($('div, pod pod--rounded'));
    _page.close();
    _ph.exit();
}).catch(function(e){
  console.log(e); 
});
```

The entire html is returned if console log just `content`. I think I'm having trouble understanding the logic of Cheerio. When I try to use Cheerio to parse things I get something that looks partly like this...

```
  'x-attribsPrefix': [Object: null prototype] {},
  children: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
  parent:
   { type: 'tag',
     name: 'td',
     namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
     attribs: [Object],
     'x-attribsNamespace': [Object],
     'x-attribsPrefix': [Object],
     children: [Array],
     parent: [Object],
     prev: null,  
     ...
```

What is this object? Is this JSON?

If in your browser you were to go to the [site](https://www.bhgre.com/Better-Homes-and-Gardens-Real-Estate-Big-Hill-5569c/Suzan-Jackson-300497a), 'inspect' the My Listings element, right click on the div `pod pod--rounded` and copy element you would have exactly what I want Node to extract from the page. Just all the html inside this div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your selector should change from `div, pod pod--rounded` to `div.pod.pod--rounded`. and according to [cheerio's documents](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#the-dom-node-object):

> Cheerio collections are made up of objects that bear some resemblence to browser-based DOM nodes.

Comment: I'll have to wait on the green check if that works because the site knows I'm using a bot now. I thought Phantom was supposed to prevent this. I know it's outside the range of the question, but have you encountered this? Can I change something in Phantom to dupe the site again?

Comment: No, I don't have any experience with phantom. @Renoldus

Comment: What's the problem of `axios` or `request`?? I used cheerio with request and everything was good. @Renoldus

Comment: I was using `axios` and it knew I was a robot after about three visits by the script. After about twenty requests with `Phantom` the site won't let my script see it anymore. I've been meaning to try from a different computer.